# Color values have the same value all over the image

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, mobile, kotlin

I have the contour of an object and the center coordinates. Now I'm trying to detect the point lying on the border of the contour, but still is on the same height (y) as the center. The background is set to black. Therefor I'm calculating the threshold image and iterate over the pixel and check if they are set to white or not. The problem is that according to my code all values are 0.

Tried working on the original image as well. The problem still occurs, I always get 0/255/255. No matter if I'm inside the object or on the background.

```
private fun calcPointOnContour(point: Point, image: Mat): Point {
    var pointOnContour = Point()
    val ycrcb = getCbComponent(image)
    val imageThresh = getThresholdImage(ycrcb)

    for (i in point.x.toInt() until image.cols()) {
        val pixel = imageThresh.get(i, point.y.toInt())

        if (pixel[0] < 255) {
            pointOnContour = Point(i.toDouble(), point.y)
            break
        }
    }

    return pointOnContour
}

private fun getCbComponent(mat: Mat): Mat {
    val ycrcb = Mat(mat.rows(), mat.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3)
    val lYCrCb = ArrayList<Mat>(3)

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, ycrcb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
    Core.split(mat, lYCrCb)

    return lYCrCb[2]
}

private fun getThresholdImage(mat: Mat): Mat {
    val imageThresh = Mat.zeros(mat.rows(), mat.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
    Imgproc.threshold(mat, imageThresh, 100.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY)

    return imageThresh
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Imgproc.threshold` is a method that converts your image to binary based on the threshold values you have provided. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

And you have provided `maxVal` as 255 and hence only 0 or 255.

====

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, ycrcb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
Core.split(mat, lYCrCb)
```

I think it should be `Core.split(ycrcb, lYCrCb)`

Also, can you add the code where you are creating the original Mat from the image? Maybe, there's some issue there.

Comment: You're totally right about Core.split(ycrcb, lYCrCb). It was a leftover from my attempt to check if the color values differ in the original image. The entire code which is used before these specific methods would be a little bit too much to post it in here, but basically I load a jpeg image from my external storage, filter the background and crop the image to the region of interest.

Comment: Can be closed...flipped the values in image.get()...Thanks for having a look into this as well :)